# Jobs not firing but configured SQS

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and i have configured SQS. I have an email send event which is handled in a controller. I see it it is called but it is not sending the email. What is the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common case when you are not running queue worker. Check [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#the-queue-work-command). Start your worker by using `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: Thank you, i got a bunch of queued jobs after i ran the command.